# Python - can someone tell me what these two lines do?

Tags: python, c, string

I'm trying to convert this Python code to C. But for the life of me, I can't figure out what this line here does. The rest of the program seems simple.

```
self.payload = "\x02\x00%s%s" % (
    pack(">b", length),
    "".join(random.choice(string.printable) for i in range(length)))
```

If anybody could give me a rough idea of what this is doing, it'd be much appreciated!

Comment: does length end up being a number between 18 and (18+19) since for example 19 % 20 will give you 19?

Comment: @NayukiMinase apparently it returns a string representing binary data? I'm honestly not sure. This is all very new to me and the Python docs aren't of much help for someone unfamiliar.

Comment: @AnthonyHurst good question. I could probably implement that a bit better in C. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First line:

- The correct translation of `length = random.randint(18, 20)` is `int length = rand() % 3 + 18`.

Now let's dissect the dense second line piece by piece.

- `"\x02\x00%s%s" % (x, y)` means to substitute the format string with the given arguments (like `sprintf()`). In this case it means concatenating the bytes 0x02, 0x00 with two strings `x` and `y` to follow.
- `x = pack(">b", length)` uses [`struct.pack()`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html). In this case, it means to convert the integer value `length` into one byte representing its value. It's almost equivalent to using [`chr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#chr).
- `y = "".join(z)` means to take each element in the list `z` (which must be a string) and concatenate them with "" (nothing) between them. (For example, `"@".join(["a","b","c"]) --> "a@b@c"`.)
- `z = (random.choice(string.printable) for i in range(length))` returns a generator object. You can think of it as a list whose elements are computed on demand. In this case, it generates `length` elements where each element is one character randomly chosen from the string [`string.printable`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.printable).

All in all, the second line yields a string that starts wxth 0x02 0x00, followed by `(char)length`, followed by `length` random characters each uniformly chosen from the set of chars `string.printable`.

Comment: So if I'm not mistaken, `pack(">b", length)` is the big-endian, signed char representation of whatever length equals?

So if `length` equals 74, the output of the `pack()` call would be the big endian `"J"`?

Comment: Ahh, I see, thanks! Two last questions, then. Does there need to be any sort of padding in between all of those elements, or can it just be `"0x020x00(char)length(random stuff)"`? And two, does it matter what is actually in the random characters? Or can I just use more rand() calls and cast them as chars until I get `length` number of chars?

Comment: Padding: There is no padding. string.printable: Extract the string and use the same string in the C code.

Comment: Alright, thanks again! If I could hug you, I would. This has been bugging me endlessly for awhile now! I suppose I have a few things to learn about data representation. Namely hex, and byte order.

Comment: @eryksun Yup, that's correct. I suppose the spirit of the algorithm is more important than its subtle flaws.